# Push to talk over cellular(PoC) client and server

Tags: java, groovy

Is there any open source PoC server and client software(Framework) for java to manage SIP and support RTP and RTCP with App Packet messages preferebly support TBCP?

Our project is to send and receive realtime voice and video over cell phones and manage sessions which created for participants and one of them can send his voice and images(his video) at the time and other participants can only receive his voice and video at the same time (exactly like Walkie Talkie with voice and video). i just know PoC servers can manage these conditions but i couldnt find any framework or server to handle it.

is there any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything like this out there.  I work with VOIP and mobile devices for a living, and have never found a framework like this.

Comment: thank you william ive found azetti but i couldnt find any documentation i dont know is it usefull or not. FMJ is a framework which apparently will support capture, playback, process, and stream media across multiple platforms but the project is under development and the last release was at 2007!! meybe it is stopped.

Comment: Ah, please post and accept your own answer if this is the case.  I'd personally be very interested in this if it works for you.